# How to make elements height in a row depend on main element height?

Tags: html, css

I have such a primitive markup:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
<div id="important" style="min-width:400px">important important important important important important important important important important important important important important important important important important</div>
<div id="unimportant" style="overflow-y:scroll">unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant unimportant </div>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

I would like it to have behave, so that if unimportant content is higher than important one, then scroll activates and it has the same height now. Is it possible in pure CSS? If no, then why?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, in your code example, I do have a scroll.  what do you mean by *then scroll activates and it has the same height now.*

Comment: @TamirAbutbul scroll is inactive when I run the code and unimportant div has bigger height than important div contents height is